# How to fscanf a combination of float and string?

Tags: matlab, formatting

The data is like this

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
```

while I read it using this

```
data = fscanf(file, '%f,%f,%f,%f,%s');
```

and it turned out that `data` is an array of float rather than a combination of float and string. So how do I read this data from txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Matlab docs for fscanf:

> Output Arguments
>
> A: An array.
>
> If the format includes:
>
> Only numeric specifiers, A is numeric. ...
>
> Only character or
>   string specifiers (%c or %s), A is a character array. ...
>
> **A
>   combination of numeric and character specifiers, A is numeric, of
>   class double. MATLAB converts each character to its numeric
>   equivalent. This conversion occurs even when the format explicitly
>   skips all numeric values (for example, a format of '%*d %s').**

So your best bet is to read everything in as strings, and then convert the numeric strings to numeric values, using str2num or str2double or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since you know there are 4 floating point values that really store a floating point value, and then the rest store the numeric ASCII values for the string, you can always split up your data and cast the part you know should be a string to char. Something like:

flt = data(1:4);
str = char(data(5:end));